# CMAKE not giving git hash under vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, cmake

On a windows 10 machine, with CMake, Git and VSCode installed I have a settings.cmake file, containing the following code:

```html
# git git hash
execute_process(COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_HASH)
IF (GIT_HASH)
    string(STRIP "${GIT_HASH}" GIT_HASH)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "${GIT_HASH}")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DCONFIG_GIT_HASH=${GIT_HASH}")
ENDIF()
```

This file is included in my CMakeLists.txt
I use this to insert the git hash in my software

When running CMake from the commandline (Windows 10) this will result in a define of the CONFIG_GIT_HASH.
When run from within VsCode CONFIG_GIT_HASH stays undefined.

Comment: Probably, `git` behaves differently in the command line and from the VSCode. Have you tried to print value of `GIT_HASH` variable in both cases? You may also obtain an exit code of `git` via `RESULT_VARIABLE` option for `execute process`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that Cmake was called with an almost empty "PATH" environment.
The solution was adding

```
    "cmake.configureEnvironment": {
        "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd"
    },
```

in the settings.json